# Primitive full-text search on some properties of an object

Tags: search, typescript

I am not a JS/TS Guru, so i wanted to ask if one could write this better.

I needed a very primitive Full-Text-Search of some properties of an Object. What do you think?

```
export const search = <T, K extends keyof T>(term: string, objects: T[], keys: K[]): T[] => {
  const foundObjects = objects.filter(x => {
    for (const key of keys) {
      if (x.hasOwnProperty(key) === false) {
        continue;
      }

      const val = x[key];

      if (typeof val === 'string' && val.toLowerCase().includes(term)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
  return foundObjects;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of code that is not needed.

- The two `continue` are not needed.
- Rather than assign the variable `foundObjects` the filtered result just return the result directly.
- The variable `val` that holds the property can be side stepped.
- Then the `hasOwnProperty` can be combined with the if statement
- Rather than use the for loop you can also use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to find if any item matches the search

Thus you get

```
export const search = <T, K extends keyof T>(term: string, objects: T[], keys: K[]): T[] => {
    return objects.filter(x => 
        keys.some(key => 
            x.hasOwnProperty(key) && 
            typeof x[key] === 'string' && 
            x[key].toLowerCase().includes(term)
        )
    );
};
```

Comment: Thx. I learned something new. One small issue with your solution. (I had the same thats why this `val` variable is there). `x[key].toLowerCase()` throws a `Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'T[K]'` error. I know its a TS issue, but thats the only small "issue". Thx again.